# Obtaining and limiting get_terms() from custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop

I have a custom taxonomy called `type`.

```
register_taxonomy(  
    'type',  
    'type', 
    array(  
        'hierarchical' => true,  
        'label' => 'Type',  
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'type', 
            'with_front' => false
        ) 
    )
);
```

On my blog template, I'm trying to obtain the checked value from this taxonomy ... and then limit it to 1.

**My approach:**

```
$terms = get_terms("type"); 
$count = count($terms); 

if ( $count > 0 && !empty($terms)){ 
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
        echo '<li class="postLabel__type"><a href="'.get_term_link($term->term_id).'"' . $term->name . '</a></li>'; 
        if( $count >= 1 ) break; // only show one category tag
    }
}
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

- If no `type` is checked, don't echo `.postLabel__type` li.
- If more than one `type` is checked, only show 1.

**Current results:**

- Prints out `postLabel__type` li for all posts, even if the checkbox is not ticked.
- Prints out the first type option in the checkbox list (so if `blog 1` has `type 2` checked, it will print `type 1` because it's the first one in the list).

**Taxonomy in backend:**

[image]

Comment: What checkboxes are you talking about? I don’t see you handling anything that looks like an external form parameter anywhere here.

Comment: @misorude - Have edited my question showing the custom taxonomy checkboxes

Comment: So you don’t want to get all terms that exist, but those that are actually _assigned_ to a _specific_ post? Then start by using `wp_get_post_terms` instead of `get_terms`.